# Rails where query order by index of array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to figure out a way I can order the following query by index in that array...

```
@books_sorted.map(&:id) => ["31f1d544-4ce5-4bcd-89fd-8a76e4c052fe",
 "1ccaab81-9443-40b6-9f0e-06b799377d9e",
 "622ebbdf-4eb9-4b2e-879a-5d93c0bdfb29",
 "1e255968-6094-4bdb-90de-9c0922a0ad4e",
 "14d08406-3136-48e4-84c9-314a652ccf34"]

@books = @books.where("books.id in (?)", @books_sorted.map(&:id)) if @books_sorted.any?
```

Comment: Are you using MySql ?

Comment: I guess, he means `map`

Comment: PG - and yes, i meant map. sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
@books_sorted.collect {|book| @books.detect{|x| x.id == book.id}} if @books_sorted.any?
```

Please note: This isn't a efficient solution, since we are doing the sort in ruby instead of database query. 
Hope it helps :)

Comment: thank so much for this.  Is this considered an N+1 query?

Comment: Am very glad that it helped. I don't think this is N+1 query. N+1 queries occur when there is a 1-many relationship. Wait a moment, I will try to find good example.

Comment: The accepted answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue demonstrates N+1 queries pretty well with car and its wheels example.

Comment: Well, having one more look. Even though there is not 1-many relationship. This seems N+1 now. Because 1 query for getting `@books` and N queries then to get them in correct order. But I am not an expert on this subject to comment if it qualifies as N+1 or not.